# What does "$|i-j|$ is a square" means in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, algebraic-graph-theory

I am reading a pastime from issue 6 of "Le Monde 2"

-a) What is the size of the largest set $S\subset\{0,...,x\}$ such that it does not contain two integers $i$, $j$ such that $|i-j|$ is a square?

-b) What is the size of the largest set $T\subset\{0,...,x\}$ such that given two integers $i$, $j$ of $T$, $|i-j|$ is a square?

What I understand by "$|i-j|$ is a square" is that from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ it can be found a graph such as
[graph square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMmbE.png)
but I am not really sure what it means by that

Comment: I think it means that $|i-j|\ne k^2$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: Your problem statement has no "graph", just sets of nonnegative numbers (presumably whole numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a graph $G$ with nodes $\{0,1,\dots,x\}$ and an edge $(i,j)$ if $|i-j|=k^2$ for some integer $k$.  Part (a) is asking you to find a maximum independent in $G$.  Part (b) is asking you to find a maximum clique in $G$, equivalently, a maximum independent set in the complement of $G$.